# How remove need of using " ./ " before running a file in ubuntu terminal window?

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal, console

I am using ubuntu's terminal window to run some c files. after a gcc of a file I need to check the a.out output file and it's really annoying to type " ./ " each time.
I understand there is a way to lose it. How can I do it?

Comment: Is it really???

Comment: You cannot run C files. You can compile C files into executables and run those. Calling an executable from shell is not related to the programming language that was initially used. The C tag is not required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the current directory "." to your search path.  For example;

```
export PATH=./:$PATH
```

It's better to append it to the PATH like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

Comment: It's generally not recommended to add . to your path. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come for more information. If you do decide to add it though, it's probably better to add it at the end of the PATH instead of the beginning. See the accepted answer in that link for more details.